# `TypeVar`: parametric type as a value for `bound` parameter

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy

I'd like to implement a generic class like this:

```py
S = TypeVar("S")
T = TypeVar("T", bound=OtherParametrizedClass)

class MyClass(Generic[T[S]]):
    def some_method(param: S) -> None:
        pass
```

I've already tried the following:

```py
S = TypeVar("S")
T = TypeVar("T", bound=OtherParametrizedClass)

class MyClass(Generic[S, T[S]]):
    def some_method(param: S) -> None:
        pass
    def other_method(param: T) -> None:
        pass
```

It works as expected with MyPy. However, when Python interpreter runs this code, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable.
```

As I found, this means that `TypeVar` has no `[]` operator implemented.

Does anyone have an idea on how to obtain the solution satisfying both mypy and Python interpreter?

EDIT:
I have also tried the following:

```
S = TypeVar("S")
T = TypeVar("T", bound=OtherParametrizedClass[S])

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def some_method(param: S) -> None:
        pass
    def other_method(param: T) -> None:
        pass
```

Python interpreter doesn't give any errors/warnings. However mypy is complaining about the second line:

```
Invalid type "S"
```

Comment: Your first two snippets have syntax errors.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: You may get a better response if the question title reflected your problem - seems like you are trying to resolve mypy and Python differences.

Comment: I don't think that's possible as of now. Setting a generic class (say, `Foo`) as the bound for `TypeVar` is equivalent to setting `Foo[Any]` as the bound, the bound cannot contain free (free as in not bound) type variables. For more information, consider reading this [mypy GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3151).

Comment: What's the purpose of defining `T `? Is is just a short-hand for `OtherParametrizedClass`?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

There are basically two questions:

- why do you need to define `T`?
- why is `MyClass` `Generic[T]` instead of `Generic[S]`?

The second question is key: I think fundamentally what you're getting wrong is that you're trying to make `MyClass` `Generic[T]`, when it should simply be `Generic[S]`, at which point you don't even need to define `T`.
`other_method` can just return `OtherParametrizedClass[S]`.

Below an example that I think does what you're trying to achieve:

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

N = TypeVar("N", int, float)


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Adder(Generic[N]):
    to_add: N

    def add(self, value: N) -> N:
        return value + self.to_add


class Foo(Generic[N]):
    def get_adder(self, to_add: N) -> Adder[N]:
        return Adder(to_add)
```

Name mapping from my example to yours:

- `N` is `S`
- `Adder` is `OtherParametrizedClass`
- `Foo` is `MyClass`
- `Foo.get_adder` is `MyClass.other_method`

Comment: The point of not just using OtherParameterizedClass[S] is the same as the point of deriving the class from Generic[T] in the first place instead of using per-member type variables: you want to enforce the use of a *single* such type through the entire class.